# How can I know the jpeg quality of the read image using graphicsmagick

Tags: c++, image, graphicsmagick

When I read a jpeg image using Magick::readImages(...) function.
How can I know the estimated jpeg quality of the image?
I know how to set the quality when I wanna write the image, but it is not relevant to the quality of the original image, so for example:
when I read a jpeg image that its quality is 80% and I write it using 90% quality I will get a bigger image than the original one, since the 90% is not 90% out of the original 80%.
How can I know the jpeg quality of the read image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is impossible, period. The *JPEG quality* settings is just a number that is passed to the encoder and affects how the encoder treats the data.

It's not even percentage of anything - it is just some setting that affects how aggressively the encoder manipulates and transforms data. Wherever you see the percent sign near *JPEG quality* just ignore it - it's meaningless there.

So regardless of the encoder it is impossible to find which *JPEG quality* settings value the enocder used to produce this very image. The only way would be to obtain the original and try all reasonably possible setting values until you hit the same result.

Comment: Translated: The value you want is not stored within the JPEG file itself.

Comment: @Billy ONeal. Not only that. The "quality" range might be different depending on the encoder - some encoder might have a range from 52 to 650, so in order to be able to do something reasonable one has to know both the encoder version and the value. The latter two are highly unlikely to be stored explicitly in the produced file.

Answer (score 3):

It is neither impossible nor difficult with GraphicsMagick (or with ImageMagick). Type

> gm convert -log %e -debug coder in.jpg junk.ppm

and look in the output for the line

> Quality: nn

if the image was created by Independent JPEG Group software or

> Quality: nn (approximate)

otherwise.

You can also use

> gm identify -verbose in.png

and look at the

> Quality: nn

line; however, this doesn't distinguish between exact and approximate qualities.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For me it says 'JPEG-Quality: nn' for .jpg from a digital camera. `convert` actually says `Quality: Fine`, where `identify` returned 99. Anyway, as answers to similar questions point out - the quality can be estimated by recompressing to the same/closest size (e.g. via binary search).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but difficult. The code has to examine the image just like people do. Here's a paper on the subject http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.4621&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the JPEG metadata, you can use the following in command-line:

```
gm identify -format "%[JPEG-Quality]" your-photo.jpg
```

In C++, it might be using `IdentifyImage` : https://imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/identify_8c.html#a91079e7db05c1bad53b2dbb2b01f41ba

That said, as other users said, it's just a number generated by the software that produced the image. As a matter of fact, I can see that GM 1.4 returns nothing on a JPEG without profile information, but GM 1.3.35 does a wild guess with `jpeg.c/EstimateJPEGQuality/932/Coder` (that returns 100%).